# Convert letter grades to number

Tags: macos, microsoft-excel

In Mac Excel 2011, how can I convert a letter grade in one column to a gpa number and place it in the column next to the letter grade. I have about 70,000 grades I need to do this for.

Answer (score 5):

Since we're talking about 70000 grades, the other answers will create a much larger Excel file since you have the formula copied all the way down.

I would recommend using `VLOOKUP` and have a separate Worksheet that would return the result. It's much less text in the formula and would accomplish the same thing.

`=VLOOKUP(B2,GPA!A:B,2,FALSE)`

List of Grades

[image]

New Worksheet with GPA Data

[image]

Comment: +1 I was waiting for someone to post this gem =)

Comment: It's much prettier to debug, easier to make changes to GPA data, etc. Plus a much smaller footprint. :)

Answer (score 1):

Use `if()` functions - `=if(A1="A","4.0")` but nest them - `=IF(A1="A",4,IF(A1="B",3,IF(A1="C",2,IF(A1="D",1,0))))`

Essentially you're saying "If it is true, then do this. If it's not, do that", but you're replacing "that" with another "if it is true, then...".

Comment: Is it possible to expand on this? Explain what the nesting `if`s do?

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this with a bunch of nested `IF()` statements and copy the formula next to every grade you need to convert.

The example below will only calculate up to an `A-` because I was lazy:

```
=IF(A1="A+",4.0,IF(A1="A",3.8,IF(A1="A-",3.6,"N/A")))
```

[image]

Comment: By using the numbers with quotation marks, excel will interpret them as text so you won't be able to use them for additional calculation.

Comment: @Raystafarian Good catch, I assumed that they could easily cast the column as a float if need-be

Comment: There are definitely ways around it, I just wanted to note it in case the OP got confused.

Answer (score 0):

If you have "+" and "-" on the letter grades, you can use this nested IF() function:

```
=IF(OR(A1="A+",A1="A",A1="A-"),4,IF(OR(A1="B+",A1="B",A1="B-"),3,IF(OR(A1="C+",A1="C",A1="C-"),2,IF(OR(A1="D+",A1="D",A1="D-"),1,0))))
```